# Symfony2 and Doctrine - Generate code on insertion

Tags: php, database, symfony, callback, doctrine

Using Symfon2.0 and Doctrine, I am trying to do the following:

1. Insert a new row in the database
2. in the moment of inserting, automatically generate a code and also insert it.
3. That code is related to the ID of the table. Something like `<something>/row_id`

How can I easily do this?

I've been trying Doctrine Livecycle callbacks. But:

- PrePersist still doesn't have the ID.
- PostPersist have the ID, but somehow the insertion has already been done and, although I can  set any property from the Entity, I don't know how to make it to be persisted "again" to the database.

Any clue overthere?

Any other way to do it properly?

Comment: Problem is: if you do something in PostPersist AND PERSIST AGAIN you'd get another PostPersist...at infinitum. Database triggers are ugly but they work.

Comment: As a workaround, he could only update the value of entity's property only if it's still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your create controller:

> ```
> if ($form->isValid()) {
>         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
>         $em->persist($entity);
>         $em->flush();
>
>         $entity->setCode($code);
>         $em->persist($entity);
>         $em->flush();
>
>         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('entity_show'
>            ,array('id' => $entity->getId())));
>     }
> ```

The second block ($entity->setCode...) is what you need to add and will need to be customized to suit your purposes

Alternatively, you can use Listeners:

> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace ormed\ormedBundle\Listener;
>
> use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs; use
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
>
> class LastModifiedListener {
>
>   private $container;
>
>   public function __construct(Container $container){$this->container = $container;}
>
>   public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
>   {
>       $entityManager = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
>       $unitOfWork = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
>
>       foreach ($unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityInsertions() AS $entity) {
>           $entity->setCode( $code );
>
>           $entityManager->persist($entity);
>           $classMetadata = $entityManager->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
>           $unitOfWork->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity);
> } } }
> ```